# I want to know the difference between print two integer 204 and 0204

Tags: php

I want to know the difference between echo `integer 204` and `0204` without quote.

```
echo 204; // output : 204
echo 0204; // output : 132
```

Comment: Start from [PHP Integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

Comment: Difference is 72 in decimal :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [#Example 1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

```
echo 204; // output : 204 because its a decimal number
echo 0204; // output : 132 because its a octal number
```

Answer (score 3):

Numbers beginning with `0` (in many programming languages) are [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) numbers. `204` outputs how you would expect because it begins with a number 1 through 9, signifying a [decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal) number. See [php's documentation on integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple the first is decimal the second is Octal

Answer (score 1):

Putting a leading zero on an integer literal in PHP code instructs PHP that the number is in Octal (base 8) format.

Echo, on the other hand, when invoked by itself with just a number, just takes the number fed to it and prints it in ordinary decimal form.

Octal 204 = Decimal 132.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php